# Visual Studio 2015 File Structure Extension

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, file-structure

someone know a Visual Studio extension for display file structure in html/cshtml file? I found this feature in VSCommand for Visual Studio and in ReSharper.

But first project for Visual Studio 2015 is abandoned and the second is not free.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

View > Other Windows > Document Outline will show a window like that.

[image: Document Outline]

Comment: yes but work only for aspx page :( not for *.cshtml page  in MVC